# Add duplicate values in a table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
Select 
    P.ProductName, WFS.Status, OI.Quantity, OI.Price 
from 
    OrderItem As OI
Inner Join 
    Order As O On OI.OrderID = O.ID AND OI.ItemType = 1
Inner Join 
    Product P On OI.ProductID = P.ID
Inner Join 
    WorfFlowStatus As WFS On O.StatusID = WFS.ID
```

This query returns the rows:

```
ProductName   Status    Quantity     Price
-------------------------------------------
ABC           Shipped      10         100
ABC           Shipped      10         100
BCE           Pending       20        200
```

Now I want to select the same product in one row but quantity and price should be added. For e.g

```
ABC        Shipped         20       200    
BCE        Pending         20       200
```

If status and productname is same than add the quantity and price and if product is not the same then no addition in quantity and price.

Comment: You need to group your data. Read about `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: hi actually i am grouping also the complete query is like this .Select P.ProductName,WFS.Status,OI.Quantity,OI.Price from OrderItem As OI Inner Join Order As O On OI.OrderID = O.ID AND OI.ItemType = 1 Inner Join Product P On OI.ProductID = P.ID Inner  Join WorfFlowStatus As WFS On O.StatusID = WFS.ID group by P.ProductName,WFS.Status,OI.Quantity,OI.Price

Comment: According to your SQL statement your are not

Comment: no you can see the one i have added in the comments section

Comment: You've got your answer, but I recommend you read about aggregate functions and GROUP BY clause in the Internet

Comment: i have unique item ID in OI table which contain the fk of workflow and products so i have item unique ID but products cane be duplilcate so i want if products are same than sum the quantity and price but the item ID is unique that why groupby doesnt work. if i am correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  P.ProductName,
  WFS.Status,
  sum(OI.Quantity),
  sum(OI.Price) 
from OrderItem As OI 
  Inner Join Order As O 
    On OI.OrderID = O.ID AND OI.ItemType = 1 
  Inner Join Product P 
    On OI.ProductID = P.ID 
  Inner Join WorfFlowStatus As WFS 
    On O.StatusID = WFS.ID
group by
  P.ProductName,
  WFS.Status
```

Comment: Adding a little bit of context, explanations, or comments could make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by cha, the `Group By` clause is the key:

```
Select P.ProductName,WFS.Status,sum(OI.Quantity),sum(OI.Price)
from OrderItem As OI 
Inner Join [Order] As O On OI.OrderID = O.ID AND OI.ItemType = 1 
Inner Join Product P On OI.ProductID = P.ID 
Inner Join WorkFlowStatus As WFS On O.StatusID = WFS.ID
group by productName, Status
```

Comment: i have tried this query but its still showing duplicate product names. i dont know what hell is wrong. i have unique item ID in OI table which contain the fk of workflow and products so i have item unique ID but products cane be duplilcate so i want if products are same than sum the quantity and price but the item ID is unique that why groupby doesnt work. if i am correct.

Comment: Because we're grouping on the ProductName and the Status, it should only group by the unique name and status, whether there are multiple products with the same name or multiple WorkFlowStatus with different Status.  Of course, if the values in the DB are slightly different, like having whitespace at the end, all bets are off.  Is there any chance you have some Products with whitespace in the name?

Comment: yes may be u r correct i will check it but my question is if one column in a row has unique value and other columns values appear duplicate in a table than group by still works, i mean two items can have same products but different quantity and price.

Comment: Group by doesn't care about anything but the columns you're grouping by.  If you group by ProductName, it disregards the ProductID, and any other product columns.  And, because aggregate operators like sum don't affect the number of rows, you could remove the sum of Quantity and Price and you'd still get the same number of rows.  Only columns to look at for whitespace are the Status and the ProductName

Comment: yes i have recreated the whole table strucuture and now things are fine. Thanks for your help thanks again.

Comment: Please be sure to mark your solution or add your own answer to explain what you did to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

'over with Partition by' can help.
For example

select ProductName, 
       Status, 
       Quantity, 
       (SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName)) as TotalQuantity
FROM YourTableName and joins

Answer (score 0):

```
select P.ProductName, WFS.Status, sum(OI.Quantity), sum(OI.Price)
from OrderItem OI, Order O, Product P, WorkFlowStatus WFS
where OI.OrderID = O.ID and OI.ItemType = 1 and
      OI.ProductID = P.ID and
      O.StatusID = WFS.ID
group by productName, Status
```

Comment: To add duplicate values in a table you have to use group by clause.